# d occurrence out of successive attempts

Tags: probability

The probability of something happening at least once out of successive attempts is solved by the equation where p is the probability and n is the number of attempts:

$$f(p, n)=1-(1-p)^{n} $$

I want to figure out the probability of it happening more than once given by the variable d.

For $d=0$, the equation should return $1$.

For $d=1$, the equation should be $f(p, n)$.

For $d=n$, the equation is $p^{d}$.

Finally, the equation returns $0$ when $d>n$.

Comment: It seems your formula at the top is for event happening at least once (rather than exactly once). Can you explain a bit what the variable $d$ means?

Comment: @coffeemath That is what I meant. Sorry. d is the number of it happening at minimum.

Comment: The probability of the event occurring at least $d$ times in $n$ trials is given by
$$ P(k \ge d) = \sum_{k=d}^n \binom nk p^k (1-p)^{n-k}   $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly clear to me what you're asking, but it sounds like you want to find the probability of getting at least $d$ occurrences out of $n$, given that the probability of success on any attempt is $p$.

Let $X$ be the number of successful attempts/occurances out of $n$, so that as you state:

For $d=0$ we have $P(X \geq d) = 1$

For $d=1$ we have $P(X \geq d) = 1 - (1-p)^n$

And obviously for $d=n$ we have $P(X \geq d) = P(X = d) = p^d$.

All of that is correct as you say.

The key observation here is that $X$ is a Binomial random variable. We have $n$ attemps, a number of successes $d$, and each attempt has probability of success $p$.

The [Binomial probability function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) is:

$P(X=d) =$ $n \choose d$ $p^d \times (1-p)^{n-d}$

And explanation for what $n \choose d$ means is [given here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). It basically gives us the "number of ways of choosing $d$ objects from a total of $n$ so that order does not matter".

So therefore $P(X \geq d) = \sum_{i=d}^n P(X=i) = \sum_{i=1}^n$ $n \choose i$ $p^i \times (1-p)^{n-i}$

This formula satisfies all of the conditions you require.

$P(X \geq 1) = 1 - P(X = 0) = 1-$$n \choose 0$ $p^0 (1-p)^{n-0} = 1- (1-p)^n$ etc.